# Is it possible successfully to downgrade HP Pavilion 14-dv2003nl from Windows 11 to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, operating-systems, downgrade

I am buying the notebook HP Pavilion 14-dv2003nl who's operating system is Windows 11 Home. I work with STM32CubeIde and it doesn't support Windows 11,therefore I must downgrade this laptop to Windows 10.
Buying a laptop already with W10 is not possible (personal reasons). Could anyone of you tell me if this laptop model works correctly with Windows 10?

Comment: I would be shocked if any x86 desktop application that supports Windows 10 was incompatible with with Windows 11. Have you verified the application is actually incompatible with Windows 11 yourself? Device driver support is different due to the way Windows handles compatibility.

Comment: @Ramhound Device drivers may just be the thing. This is a development environment for micro-controllers that includes drivers for development boards (JTAG, serial, USB). If those drivers are essentially Win7 with just enough basic updates to make it work on Windows 10, they may be problematic on Windows 11. (Not uncommon in the embedded devices industry.) On the other hand is may "just work" and the vendor just hasn't bothered to extensively test on Windows 11 and therefor calls it unsupported.

Comment: @Tonny - The IDE website just mentions "Windows", so I am wondering if the author, is concluding there isn't support because it doesn't specifically mention that fact. When I mention device drivers I am talking more about (Sound, GPU, etc) due to the ini file not  mentioning the support.

Comment: @Ramhound I assumed you meant drivers coming with the application. But either way driver support is the key in this. Any normal Windows 10 application should work fine on Windows 11.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer the question if Windows 10 will work correctly on this model,
but I can make these remarks:

- The CPU is 11th generation Intel Core mobile processor,
  so doesn't need Windows 11 for full efficiency
- HP does not support Windows 10 on this model and does not offer any
  updates for it, as you can see on
  [Software and drivers for HP Pavilion 14 Laptop PC 14-dv2000](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-pavilion-14-laptop-pc-14-dv2000/2101006186).
  This is a very big danger sign.

In short, after installing Windows 10, you will be using the Windows 10
generic drivers, with no possibility of getting drivers from HP for
Windows 10. I only remark that the driver model for both Windows versions
are nearly identical, so there is an excellent chance that Windows 11
drivers will also work on Windows 10, but no certainty.

Installing Window 10 over Windows 11 requires a clean install.
You would be losing all the HP-specific products and drivers installed
by HP, which might be problematic.

You could perhaps solve the problem by staying in Windows 11 and
creating a Window 10 virtual machine to make STM32CubeIde work.
You would be losing performance (if that's important for you).

Comment: _"You would be losing performance"_ - not necessarily. With modern virtualization CPU overhead is negligible. GPU is a different story though and running another OS will eat up significant amount of RAM. But if the program isn't very graphics-intensive, doesn't rely on specific GPU features (CUDA, OpenCL, NVENC…) and there's enough RAM, then OP may not even notice a difference.

Comment: VM could be problematic. STM32CubeIde is a IDE for STM microcontrollers, which, IIRC also has a emulator/debugger environment. Those usually don't work in a VM (nested virtualisation) which could be a major showstopper for the poster. Also quite possible that connections to a debug board (JTAG, USB, serial) wont; work properly in a VM.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, if you've upgraded within recent 10 days.

Check this step-by-step guide:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhEHDXObBdI

Hope this helps!

Source: [Can I Downgrade Windows 11 to Windows 10 in my HP laptop?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/can-i-downgrade-windows-11-to-windows-10-in-my-hp/0c138d57-4803-4dcc-b784-988497b8c05d)

Comment: The authors device came with Windows 11. Your answer isn’t applicable to the author’s situation. We want instructions to exist in the body of an answer instead of a link to a YouTube video